# How can I simulate binary values using a vector of booleans in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, binary

I want to be able to retain the same amount of `bits` to my vector whilst still performing binary addition. For example.

```
int numOfBits = 4;
int myVecVal = 3;
vector< bool > myVec;
GetBinaryVector(&myVec,myVecVal, numOfBits);
```

and its output would be:

```
{0, 0, 1, 1}
```

I don't know how to make a function of `GetBinaryVector` though, any ideas?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829854/how-to-store-a-bit-array-in-c?

Comment: It needs to retain the same size bits though, not adjust them to the size of the value. Ie, a value of 30 will have a size of 5, no more no less. Or unless I specified its size, which I have, so I can also have a value of 30 but a size of 100 for example. @AllanWind

Comment: What should happen on overflow?

Comment: Nothing, It can crash or it should just be all 1's, (unsigned integer). It really doesn't matter for my use case

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to work (although the article I added in initial comment seem to suggest you only have byte level access):

```
void GetBinaryVector(vector<bool> *v, int val, int bits) {
    v->resize(bits);
    for(int i = 0; i < bits; i++) {
        (*v)[bits - 1 - i] = (val >> i) & 0x1;
    }
}
```

The left hand side sets the i'th least significant bit which is index `bits - 1 - i`.  The right hand side isolates the i'th least significant bit by bit shifting the value down i'th bit and masking everything but the least significant bit.

In your example `val = 8`, `bits = 15`.  In the first iteration `i = 0`: we have `(*v)[15 - 1 - 0] = (8 >> 0) & 0x1`.  `8` is binary `1000` and shifting it down `0` is `1000`. `1000 & 0x1` is `0`.  Let's jump to `i = 4`: `(*v)[15 - 1 - 4] = (8 >> 4) & 0x1`.  `1000 >> 4` is `1` and `1 & 0x1` is `1`, so we set `(*v)[10] = 1`.  The resulting vector is `{ 0, ..., 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 }`

Comment: I entered 15, 8 and it gave me the reverse of the value 15 in binary

Comment: Updated the assignment to use bits-i instead.  Give it a whirl.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, bits is like a length and using it as an index so need [bits - 1 - i].

Comment: Why are you passing a pointer to a vector rather than just returning one?

Comment: The original question had a &myVec as the first argument when invoked.

Comment: I really like how simple it is, but I dont understand how it works though, like how does it even know what values to set to 1

Comment: I wrote something up on how the code works, and gave a couple of example runs.